# How to combine two bitmaps vertically (using LockBits, and BitmapData)

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing, gdi+, system.drawing

I need a function in C# that returns merged bitmaps vertically. I want the resulting image to contain two bitmaps set one above the other. I don't have much experience with processing images in unsafe mode. I have a method that merges images vertically using GDI+, but there are distortions in the pixels.

Please help.

```
public static Bitmap merge_Two_Bitmaps32bppArgb_Vertically(Bitmap imageSrc1, Bitmap imageSrc2) {
  Bitmap returnMapOut = null;
  int maxW = (
    new List < int > () {
      imageSrc1.Width,
        imageSrc2.Width
    }
  ).Max();

  returnMapOut = new Bitmap(
    maxW,
    (imageSrc1.Height + imageSrc2.Height), //sum !!!
    PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb
  );

  //src 1:
  BitmapData bitmapDataSrc1 = imageSrc1.LockBits(
    new Rectangle(0, 0, imageSrc1.Width, imageSrc1.Height),
    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
    PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb
  );

  //output:
  BitmapData bitmapDataOut = returnMapOut.LockBits(
    new Rectangle(0, 0, returnMapOut.Width, returnMapOut.Height),
    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
    PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb
  );

  //TODO:

}
```

Comment: I´d not recommend going "the unmanaged way" if you don´t understand the underlying Bitmap data format properly. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap for some insights into the format specification.

Comment: What does `merge vertically` mean in the first place? `Merge` suggests you want to combine two images but `vertically` suggests you want to append one below the other. Which is easy - create a new bitmap with twice the height and draw the existing ones one after the other.

Comment: I want to append one bitmap below another bitmap with unmanaged code in C#.

Comment: @pl.lepko I added a modified version of the `MergeBitmaps` example method to my answer that demos how you can combine the images by copying raw bitmap buffers. As mentioned, I would not recommend doing this, but you asked for it (-:

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify what platform you´re targeting, I assume (for simplicity) the platform is `Windows` (because `GDI+` and the `System.Drawing` API is only fully available on that platform). Further, I assume you target one of the more recent versions of .NET, for instance, .NET 6.0 LTS.

I provide you with some sample code that avoids usage of the functionality that deals with the Stride pointer and raw image data. I use the `System.Drawing.Common` package in my example. If you´re working on an older version of the .NET Framework, adding a reference to `System.Drawing` should also work.

The following method accepts an array of `Image` objects. It takes the width and the pixel format of the first image and calculates the height of the resulting image by just summing up the heights of all images. It renders all images unscaled, so you need to tweak it to your needs; maybe you want to specify the width of the resulting image as a parameter and scale all images accordingly.

```cs
private static Image MergeBitmaps(params Image[] bitmaps)
{
    Image first = bitmaps.FirstOrDefault() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();
    int width = first.Width;
    int resultImageHeight = bitmaps.Sum(bitmap => bitmap.Height);

    var offset = 0;
    var resultImage = new Bitmap(width, resultImageHeight, first.PixelFormat);
    using Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resultImage);
    foreach (Image bitmap in bitmaps)
    {
        g.DrawImageUnscaled(bitmap, 0, offset, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
        offset += bitmap.Height;
    }

    return resultImage;
}
```

Also, I would use the `Image` type rather than `Bitmap`. You could use the provided example method as follows:

```cs
using Image bitmap1 = Image.FromStream(...);
using Image bitmap2 = Image.FromStream(...);
using Image mergedImage = MergeBitmaps(bitmap1, bitmap2);
mergedImage.Save(Path.Combine(path, "merged.bmp"));
```

As mentioned in my comment, you should only work the raw bitmap data if you developed an understanding of how the pixel information in the buffer is laid out. Your implementation may require calculations and pixel conversions to support images of different pixel formats. If performance is not an issue, having code, as provided in my example, that renders the target image using a `Graphics` object may be less complex and easier to work with.

**Update**

If you want to combine the images by copying the raw bitmap buffers into the resulting image, ensure all input images have the same width and pixel format, and the pixel format also matches the format of the resulting image (which is `32bppArgb` in that case). Then you could try something like this (this needs proper testing and additional checks):

```cs
private static Image MergeBitmaps(params Bitmap[] bitmaps)
{
    int width = bitmaps.Max(bitmap => bitmap.Width);
    int resultImageHeight = bitmaps.Sum(bitmap => bitmap.Height);

    var offset = 0;
    var pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
    var resultImage = new Bitmap(width, resultImageHeight, pixelFormat);

    foreach (Bitmap bitmap in bitmaps)
    {
        int bitmapHeight = bitmap.Height;
        var rectangle = new Rectangle(0, offset, width, bitmapHeight);

        CopyBitmap(resultImage, rectangle, bitmap);

        offset += bitmapHeight;
    }

    return resultImage;
}

private static void CopyBitmap(
    Bitmap destBitmap, 
    Rectangle destinationRectange, 
    Bitmap sourceBitmap)
{
    BitmapData resultBitmapData = destBitmap.LockBits(destinationRectange, 
        ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, 
        destBitmap.PixelFormat);
    try
    {
        var bytes = new byte[resultBitmapData.Stride * resultBitmapData.Height];
        var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height);
        BitmapData bitmapData = sourceBitmap.LockBits(rect, 
            ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, 
            sourceBitmap.PixelFormat);
        try
        {
            var array = new byte[bitmapData.Stride * bitmapData.Height];
            Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, array, 0, array.Length);
            Array.Copy(array, bytes, array.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            sourceBitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        }

        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, resultBitmapData.Scan0, bytes.Length);
    }
    finally
    {
        destBitmap.UnlockBits(resultBitmapData);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have such an implementation but I am not satisfied with its results.

Comment: Maybe I can give you some more tips if you could describe what makes the results you received not as good as expected.

Comment: I have a bitmap from the DataGridView control - obtained with the "drawToBitmap()" method. After printing this image is correct, but when I combine it with another bitmap using given function, the letters in the image have a blue tint in some places.

Comment: Blue tint has nothing to do with drawing images. Neither do grids. Perhaps you're using a format like GIF which has a limited palette? Perhaps the original images are GIFs and their palettes are different? `After printing` if you want to print, why not use a [PrintDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) and draw to the document's `Graphics` class?

Comment: If you compare the browser and the printed document, perhaps the difference is caused by color differences between monitors, browsers and the printer?

Comment: Don't use `Image.FromFile()` like that, you're discarding ICM information. Use instead `Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes([File Path])), true, false)` -- This: `mergedImage.Save(Path.Combine(path, "merged.bmp"));` generates a PNG not a BMP -- As noted, won't work with paletted images (if that's the case here)

Comment: @Jimi Chances are high that people just copy+paste solutions from SO and don´t overthink it; you have a point. On the other hand, we won´t be able to cover every aspect here.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. You don't need to *cover every aspect*, but the basics yes, you do. For example, you have to duplicate all source images and convert them to 32Bit ARGB before you attempt any operation. The ICM information (when present, always when an Image comes from a smartphone or a professional camera) must be preserved, otherwise the colors won't match the original -- Specifying a file extension as BMP as in `mergedImage.Save(Path.Combine(path, "merged.bmp"));` when the image, saved like that, is actually a PNG, is also *not great*

Comment: @Jimi You are right; you need to consider many things if you want a proper solution (but all those aspects might be out of scope regarding the question and answer). He wanted to know how he could combine the images by just copying image bits into the target image buffer instead of painting them.

Comment: In this case, as input for the `LockBits` on the source images, it's better to force `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb` instead of using `sourceBitmap.PixelFormat`. The `LockBits` function is perfectly capable of converting the input data to the desired format if it happens to be different, but if you don't do that and they _don't_ match, and you just blindly try to copy the data as if it were 32bpp, you're going to have corrupted output and/or crashes.